# How to submit records in two models at the same time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to submit 2 model via one form.
Despite I created these codes, the form creates only "Article" record.
"ArticleHistory" record should be created in this form. But at the moment, the form won't.

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? How come?

Here's my view(slim).

```
h2 It's new article
p test
= form_for @article do |f|
  = f.fields_for :article_history do |af|
    .field
      = af.label :title
      br
      = af.text_field :title
    .field
      = af.label :content
      br
      = af.text_area :content
    = af.hidden_field :id
  .field
    = f.hidden_field :status, :value => "publish"
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id
  = f.hidden_field :current_version, :value => 1
  .actions
    = f.submit 'submit'
```

Also my model.

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :article_histories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_histories
end

class ArticleHistory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

And here's controller. I quoted only necessary part.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.article_histories.build
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.status == "publish"
      @article.publish_datetime = Time.now.to_s(:db)
    end

    if params[:article][:back]
      render :new
    elsif @article.save
      redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:current_version , :status , :user_id , article_histories_attributes:[:id, :article_id, :version, :title, :content])
  end
end
```

BTW these are version information.

```
$ bin/rails -v
Rails 5.0.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Thanks in advance!

**[ActiveRecord Error]**

```
Started POST "/articles" for ::1 at 2017-01-13 12:10:35 +0900
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZUMBqozYl4vWNxImgz8ghY7gGb2NPp4qMnXYulqkoPAMTWueIN8xAITCo7NSDP/rDgJQOLNOEqLwUcy3kl4BTQ==", "article"=>{"article_history"=>{"title"=>"title1210", "content"=>"content1210", "id"=>""}, "status"=>"publish", "user_id"=>"9", "current_version"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"確認"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 9 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameter: article_history
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO `articles` (`current_version`, `status`, `publish_datetime`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 'publish', '2017-01-13 03:10:43', 9, '2017-01-13 03:11:05', '2017-01-13 03:11:05')
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Normally you break this out with [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), which you have configured here, but I don't see the `article_params` method where those params are extracted. Are you properly accepting them there? They might be ignored otherwise.

Comment: @tadman Ooops! Sorry I almost forgot. I add the code you mentioned as above. Could you examine that?

Comment: It might be worth calling `save!` to get an exception if that model or any of the nested ones fail validation, then `rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` if that's the case. Exceptions are hard to ignore. Also check in `log/development.log` that it's actually trying to create the record.

Comment: Thanks! I appended the error you mentioned a while ago in question. Could you examine?

Answer (score 2):

inside your `elsif @article.save` you can call

```
   ArticleHistory.create(article_params)
```

or since they are associated then you can simple call (im not completely sure about "article_histories" you can try in you console)

```
@article.article_histories.create(article_params)
```

then you can change the `article_params` to the parameters needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I inserted the line along with your advise, and then run again. But unfortunately, an error is shown like this.
"unknown attribute 'current_version' for ArticleHistory."

Comment: that error may be because article_params has "current_version" parameter while in your table Article History there is nothing called current_version. I suggest to add the attributes manually like for example ArticleHistory.create(id: 1, any_param: "value", any_param: params[:your_params])

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, It's my mistake. I noticed my error.

My form is originally like this.

```
h2 It's new article
p test
= form_for @article do |f|
  = f.fields_for :article_history do |af|
```

Changed into this

```
h2 It's new article
p test
= form_for @article do |f|
  = f.fields_for :article_histories do |af|
```

Finally, it works. Thank you all contributions!

Comment: This should be the way to do it.